# Is it possible to print contents from a specific selector, using .print() function?

Tags: javascript, printing

Is it possible to print contents from a specific CSS/DOM selector element, like let's say:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('div'); // where div innerHTML contains: Hello, Mars!
elem.print();
```

Is it possible to print out a specific part of the document, rather then the whole page, using JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media

Comment: yes.. just to have focus on that field!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media) to choose which elements will be printed.

```
@media print{
    .dontPrint{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```
<p>You will see me!</p>
<p class="dontPrint">You won't see me!</p>
<button>Print</button>
```

```
$("button").click(function(){
    print();
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YRpJM/)</kbd>

---

[image]

> As you can see, elements with `.dontPrint` will not show up in the print preview. You can apply this class on all the elements that you don't want it to appear.

---

### Alternative

```
@media print{
    .dontPrint{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```
<p>You will see me!</p>
<p>You won't see me!</p>
<button>Print</button>
```

```
$("button").click(function(){
    printTarget($("p:eq(0)"));
});

function printTarget(ele){                    //input target element(s)
    $(ele).data({print: true});
    $("body *").filter(function(){
        console.log($(this).data().print);
        return !$(this).data().print;
    }).addClass("dontPrint");
    print();
    $("*").removeClass("dontPrint");
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/gVWHp/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can try this (using another window)

```
function print()
{
    var printWin = window.open();
    printWin.document.write(document.getElementById('printable_div').innerHTML);
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```

[**DEMO**.](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Lx9/1/)